Cannot find SFML/Graphics.hpp despite modifying tasks.json and c_cpp_properties.json
I am getting this error when running my code:
fatal error: 'SFML/Graphics.hpp' file not found
#include \<SFML/Graphics.hpp\>

I am using a Mac along with VS Code (would like to use VS but none is supported by Mac it seems).
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <fstream>

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "imgui/imgui.h"
#include "imgui/imgui-SFML.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1280, 720), "SFML Works!");
    window.setFramerateLimit(60);
}

Build Output:
Starting build...

/usr/bin/clang++ -std=c++17 -I/opt/homebrew/opt/sfml/include -L/opt/homebrew/opt/sfml/lib /Users/me/Downloads/GP/comp4300-master/assignment1/main.cpp -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -fcolor-diagnostics -fansi-escape-codes -g -o /Users/me/Downloads/GP/comp4300-master/assignment1/main

ld: warning: dylib (/opt/homebrew/opt/sfml/lib/libsfml-system.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (14.0) than being linked (13.3)
ld: warning: dylib (/opt/homebrew/opt/sfml/lib/libsfml-window.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (14.0) than being linked (13.3)
ld: warning: dylib (/opt/homebrew/opt/sfml/lib/libsfml-graphics.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (14.0) than being linked (13.3)

Build finished with warning(s).
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

SFML Directory: /opt/homebrew/opt/sfml/include/SFML
If I do ls:
Audio               Graphics.hpp    System
Audio.hpp           Main.hpp        System.hpp
Config.hpp          Network         Window
GpuPreference.hpp   Network.hpp     Window.hpp
Graphics            OpenGL.hpp

So as you can see, the SFML folder is there along with Graphics.hpp. There are no red squiggles in my code unless I change the header files.
For example, if I did:
#include <SFML/GGGraphics.hpp> // RED SQUIGGLE

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp> // NO RED SQUIGGLE, BUT COMPILER ERROR

This would net red squiggles in the header code as there's no such thing as GGGraphics.hpp, so I infer that the Graphics.hpp is found, but there's some error.
If I used a different file, but it exists:
#include <SFML/Window.hpp> // RED SQUIGGLE

There would be red squiggles in the main function instead because I needed the Graphics.hpp for sf::RenderWindow. And of course, VS Code would tell me that Window.hpp does not exist despite it being there. Hopefully, this information is helpful.
Next, have a look at my config files located in .vscode.
tasks.json:
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: clang build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-std=c++17",
                "-I/opt/homebrew/opt/sfml/include",
                "-L/opt/homebrew/opt/sfml/lib",
                "${workspaceFolder}/main.cpp",
                "-lsfml-graphics",
                "-lsfml-window",
                "-lsfml-system",
                "-fcolor-diagnostics",
                "-fansi-escape-codes",
                "-g",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Generated task by Debugger."
        }
    ]
}

c_cpp_properties.json:
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/opt/homebrew/opt/sfml/include"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-arm64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}

What have I looked at?
This helped me with tasks.json
The most recent post on this topic, but unhelpful
VS Code configuration itself

I wish for the SFML window to pop up, and not this error. Something else I tried on my own was moving the entire SFML folder to my project directory, but while it worked in that the file was located, it was very inefficient because I needed to replace angle brackets with double quotes and reconfigure paths, which was very slow for the whole folder.
How can I get rid of the error that SFML/Graphics.hpp cannot be found?

Please copy-paste the full and complete build output from the example program you show, so we can look at the actual flags and options passed to the compiler.

Build output added! Thanks for letting me know - seems like this build output is important for me to discover my error.

"-IA/opt/homebrew/opt/sfml/include", I believe this should be: "-I/opt/homebrew/opt/sfml/include",

I tried -I with no results, unfortunately. I used GGGraphics.hpp to illustrate that the file doesn't exist and that VS Code puts red squiggles when using GGGraphics.hpp while Graphics.hpp has no red squiggles, but it has a compiler error. Graphics.hpp is the file I'm telling it to look. This makes me think that VS Code can find the file, but cannot use it for some reason.

"command": "/usr/bin/clang", should be "command": "/usr/bin/clang++", but that won't fix the build error.

After you changed the tasks.json and saved it did you verify that the build task was changed: /usr/bin/clang++ -std=gnu++14 -std=c++17 -I/opt/homebrew/opt/sfml/include -L/opt/homebrew/opt/sfml/lib /Users/me/Downloads/GP/comp4300-master/assignment1/main.cpp -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -fcolor-diagnostics -fansi-escape-codes -g /Users/me/Downloads/GP/comp4300-master/assignment1/n.cpp -o /Users/me/Downloads/GP/comp4300-master/assignment1/n ...

I have updated the build output. The clang++ thing did make changes to the build output. Edit: wait a second, I'm getting a different error, I think this might be good.

Is /Users/me/Downloads/GP/comp4300-master/assignment1/main.cpp the correct path of your source file.  Your compiler is telling you that it can't find that file.

I got a new build output - it's way different using clang++. I also used -I and -L as I got an error using -IA and -LA.

You have main.cpp listed 2 times on your clang++ line. That is the reason for the duplicate symbols error. Remove "${file}", from your tasks.json

Looks like the build error was fixed. While I couldn't fix my compiler error, I'm glad I was able to get that sorted out at least.
